# Change Magento decimal field format

Tags: magento, zend-framework, localization, internationalization, magento-1.7

I need to change Magento's default decimal format. I mean, when I save '1' to a decimal field, it becomes '10000.0000' with this '.0000' in the end.

I need to change it to another format, which uses ',' instead of '.' to separate decimal (and currency) numbers.

This is the Brazilian standard and it's not being used even after changing the store language. This change should be reflected mainly in the admin side.

Thanks a lot!

**==Edited==**
I haven't solved the problem yet. I'm using PT-BR (Brazilian Portuguese) as default language and it still using the wrong decimal character. 
It seems Magento have some not-localized price formatting (I mean, hard-coded) in a few points of code. For example: `magento\js\prototype\validation.js` at line 426 have:

```
|| (!isNaN(parseNumber(v)) && /^\s*-?\d*(\,\d*)?\s*$/.test(v));
```

but instead it needs to be

```
|| (!isNaN(parseNumber(v)) && /^\s*-?\d*(\,\d*)?\s*$/.test(v));
```

to fit into PT-BR format (or other locales to).

Am I right? Does anybody could fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've applied the following change to the file `magento\js\prototype\validation.js (line 426)`:

```
|| (!isNaN(parseNumber(v)) && /^\s*-?\d*(\,\d*)?\s*$/.test(v));
```

and also, changed the file `lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Abstract.php` by adding the first if statement:

```
public function getEscapedValue($index=null)
{
    $value = $this->getValue($index);

    if(is_numeric($value)){
        $value= number_format($value, 3, ",", ".");
    }
    ...
```

this changes have solved the problem so far. Do you see any side-effect?

Comments are welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check in admin area for this change

you go to in admin left bottom drop down

and select

```
Português (Portugal) / português (Portugal)
```

it will show you currency as you want. Also if you doesn't install you package go to

http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/list/19

download your package and add it to your

locale folder and select from configuration for front end also

hope this will sure  help you.

Comment: As I mentioned, there's already Brazilian Portuguese installed in this Magento instance but it's not enough. Price another decimal fields are required to be 'x.abc' instead 'x,abc' - Thanks for your help, any other tip? :)

Comment: i just checked with my local setup and it is working for me. can i add screen shot ? pls clear your cache. or try this solution http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/30474/

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Magento are based on Zend Framework currency locale format so the best way to do this is to change the language.xml from the Zend directory, more information is on this [great article](http://xme.im/format-magento-currency-or-number-base-on-locale).